# Gift Card API For Major Retail

Tags: api, e-commerce

I'm looking for a gift card API that will allow me to purchase gift cards from various major retailers (Target, Amazon, Best Buy, etc.).  Is something like that out there?  How are these 3rd parties selling specific brand gift cards?

Answer (score 3):

The Tango Card API does exactly that and is open source with no fees. Documentation available here: https://github.com/tangocarddev.

Comment: Just that it is not "open source", it has a RESTFul API which is based on open standards, but the server software and service itself is proprietary (not that is relevant for the question though)

Comment: We've built a ruby gem for interfacing with the Tangocard RaaS API: https://github.com/bonusly/tangocard